# Different datetime formats within the same data extension in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, datetime

In Marketing Cloud I have a data extension that holds vouchers. When these vouchers are claimed the field ClaimedDate is updated with the date and time of the voucher being claimed using this AMPscript.

```
ClaimRow('myDE','IsClaimed','ClaimedBy',@SubscriberKey)
```

Simple stuff.

The problem is that the format of the date and time registered comes in 2 different formats.

Like this: *07-08-2022  01:04:00*
and like this: *4/13/2022 1:01:39 AM*

I really want to avoid working with two different time formats.
I've seen this in other Data Extensions too - so;
**is there a way to make sure the date and time format is always the same in data extensions?**

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Did you verify the format in the CSV file by opening it in a plain text editor? I suspect this is more a matter of how the values are interpreted by your spreadsheet application. I would bet, that all the dates where the day is higher than 12, are displayed with slashes, and where the day is 12 or below, with dashes.

Comment: I agree with @LukasLunow try this answered here if u want to use in excel ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45100353/csv-file-using-mixture-of-date-formats

Comment: Thank you @LukasLunow - this was helpful. By importing differently into Excel I could get the same date format for all values.

Comment: You are welcome. I’ll post the solution as an answer for increased visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not caused by how values are stored in your data extension, but rather how Excel interprets the timestamps upon opening the csv file. You can verify this by opening the csv file in any plain text editor. Here you will see, that the values are formatted consistently across all the records.

If you need top work with the timestamps in Excel, you can import the data using following feature, to ensure correct formatting:
'*Data Tab > Get External Data*'. As you import make sure you select the appropriate date format for your date column in the csv file, e.g. MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm.